# Can't get Kdevelop under Debian to recognise a path to new #include files - specifically the Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, kdevelop

I'm running Debian buster and KDevelop and I want to try out some of the boost libraries. The boost example lambda code won't compile because it can't find the boost header file which is in /home/user/boost/boost_1_79_0/boost/lambda/.

Adding the full path to the include file just leads to another error, because the first include file includes others in the same directory.

I thought I found the solution in Project/Open Configuration/Language Support but no joy.

Comment: You add a folder to the list of include directories, check out the -I, -isystem and -iquote commandline arguments.

Comment: Command line arguments for what?  Not KDevelop!

Comment: I found a temporary solution by copying the whole boost distribution into /usr/local/include.  It's a kludge and it only works for those parts of boost that are header-only, but it works for me.  Still interested if anyone knows a way to get KDevelop to see alternate include paths.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the compiler, of course. Kdevelop is just a front-end. See `man gcc`.

Comment: Please update your post about any error message that could be helpful and give us more information about your project (like cmake, meson etc). How do you (try to) discover Boost?